# Sharing inter connection from router to switch and then wifi router again

Tags: networking, routes

I want to share my internet connection like this way below.

We are using broadband internet connection. The broadband guys has set our

main router with static ip.  202.5.56.28  .
 The router is Belking router

which has ip address 192.168.2.1 and is set to deefault gateway. This

Router has MAC address filtering enabled.

So we are using that router to share internet to our LAN Newtork. Now in

the main router I have connected a LAN Cable which is RJ45 Connector and

the cable is straight through to a 8 port switch
. From that switch I am

able to share internet connection to my laptop and other laptop.

Now the fact is that I have bought another 3g/4g small wifi router which I

have bought from Ebay from this link   http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-

Portable-3G-4G-WiFi-Wlan-Hotspot-AP-Client-150Mbps-RJ45-USB-Wireless-

Router-/371135322914

Now I want to enable wifi from this new 3g/4g wifi router. For this what I

have done is that I take a straight through cable. Connected one end to the

switch and other end to the wifi router.

I have configured it like DHCP enabled so that it gets internet

automatically. The First router has also DHCP enabled.

As the primary router has MAC address filtering so I added the secondary

router mac address white listed in the primary router.

But so far still I dont have any internet connection in my wifi from the

secondary router.

I guess I think I need a cross over cable from the switch to mmy secondary

router. I am also a network engineer but not sure what's hapening here.

As I know same device need cross over cable to share connection. As it is

router to router connection though it has a switch in middle.

Any help will be apriciated .

Thanks
Aman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. It's working now. I just put the LAN cable to the Lan port to my secondary router instead of WAN port and thus it is acting as a normal switch.

The fact is that it was not getting internet connection because of MAC address filtering. Every network does have it's own mac address. Even your android phone wifi has also it's own mac address.

I had to put every mac address to the first router to make it white listed and then it worked.

Thanks everyone for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have two DHCP server on the same network, this will usually mess up the whole network.
I don't understand what do you want to do. Do you want to use the two connexions at the same time ? Or do you want to use it as a hotspot.
The cables shouldn't be a problem as nowadays network cards automaticaly detect the types of cable.

Comment: I want to use one wire connection to my laptop from the switch ( this switch is connected to primary router) and also want a cable to connected to my secondary router from this switch to create WiFi hotspot so that I can use it in my Android mobile. Remember that primary router has Mac address filtering enabled. But I whitelisted the secondary router's Mac address

Comment: I could have use the primary router WiFi in my Android mobile but the fact is that that router WiFi is out of range. The LAN cable I have taken from my office to my house which is 95 meter long almost. That is why I need to create another hotspot in my house.and that is why I have bought a small router so that it just make WiFi hotspot. Cause for my laptop I can use the switch.

Comment: OK, so you don't need to use your secondary router as a router but as a hotspot. You can try to deactivate the router functionality and ensure the ip subnet is the same for all your devices.